# Different Approach : Simple Tip Calculator

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to assign the values of the different service levels in the tip() function under the service variable as I've started to do below? I know the alternative and likely preferred solution is to assign these values to the option values but would like to know if it can be done with if statements too.

```js
function tip() {

  var tipp = document.getElementById("bill").value;
  var split = document.getElementById("billsplit").value;
  var service = document.getElementById("service").value; //good=.3,ok=.25,bad=.2
  if service = "Good" {
    document.getElementById = ("service").innerHTML = .3;
  }


  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (tipp * service) / split;

}
```

```html
Enter Total Bill<br><br>
<input type="number" name="bill" id="bill">
<br><br> How was the Service <br><br>
<select id="service">
  <option value="Good">Good</option>
  <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
  <option value="ok">ok</option>
</select>

<br><br> How many People are sharing Bill?<br><br>

<input type="number" name="billsplit" id="billsplit">

<button type="button" onclick="tip()">CALCULATE</button>

<br><br>Result : <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: With `innerHTML=` on a `select` element you should only define `option` elements. Anything else is not valid HTML, even if it is just `.3`. Such text in a `div` or `option` is fine, just not directly in a `select`. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. There is no problem. I can get the calc to work fine. I'm trying to learning HTML/JS and I think learning is best done by exploring all potential avenues by which problems might be solved, not just the most obvious ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an associative array. Your `tip()` function could be like this.

```
function tip() {
            let service_values = {
                "Good": 0.3,
                "ok": 0.25,
                "Bad": 0.2
            };

            var tipp = document.getElementById("bill").value;
            var split = document.getElementById("billsplit").value;
            var service_label = document.getElementById("service").value; //good=.3,ok=.25,bad=.2
            let service = service_values[service_label];


            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= (tipp*service)/split;

        }
```

EDIT: Check the code snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<h3> Tip Calculator <h3>

        <script>

            function tip() {
                let service_values = {
                    "Good": 0.3,
                    "ok": 0.25,
                    "Bad": 0.2
                };

                var tipp = document.getElementById("bill").value;
                var split = document.getElementById("billsplit").value;
                var service_label = document.getElementById("service").value; //good=.3,ok=.25,bad=.2
                let service = service_values[service_label];


                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= (tipp*service)/split;

            }
        </script>

        <body>

        Enter Total Bill<br><br>
        <input type="number" name="bill" id="bill" value="10">
        <br><br>

        How was the Service <br><br>
        <select id="service">
            <option value ="Good">Good</option>
            <option value ="Bad">Bad</option>
            <option value ="ok">ok</option>
        </select>

        <br><br>
        How many People are sharing Bill?<br><br>

        <input type="number" name="billsplit" id="billsplit" value="1">

        <button type="button" onclick="tip()">CALCULATE</button>

        <br><br>Result : <span id="result"></span>

        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Something might be missing - the output when you try to CALCULATE is NaN. I get that you're trying to get the associated value of the inputted service level from the services value array with             let service = service_values[service_label];
 but is that just returning the actual string not the number?

Comment: In javascript its called an object literal and not an associative array (which is a PHP term for the monstrosity that is the do everything arrays in PHP).

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object to map the value against the service grade. Note: you'll need to coerce your input values from strings to numbers before you do any calculation on them.

```js
// cache all the needed elements
const billTotal = document.querySelector('#bill');
const splitValue = document.querySelector('#split');
const service = document.querySelector('#service');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// use a event listener instead of an inline function
button.addEventListener('click', calculate, false);

// map the values to service terms
const serviceMap = {
  good: 0.3,
  ok: 0.25,
  bad: 0.2
}

function calculate() {

  // get the input values
  const bill = Number(billTotal.value);
  const split = Number(splitValue.value);

  // get the selected service grade
  const serviceGrade = service.options[service.selectedIndex].value;

  // get the service value from the object using the grade as the key
  const serviceValue = serviceMap[serviceGrade];

  // perform the calculation
  const total = ((bill * serviceValue) / split).toFixed(2);

  // output the result with `textContent`
  result.textContent = `Total ${total}  ((${bill} * ${serviceValue}) / ${split})`;
}
```

```css
input, button, div {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
Bill <input id="bill" type="number" />
Split <input id="split" type="number" />
Service <select id="service">
  <option value="good">Good</option>
  <option value="ok">Bad</option>
  <option value="bad">ok</option>
</select>
<button type="calculate">Calculate</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```